# Drag and Drop Routing in JavaScript

Tags: routes, leaflet, drag-and-drop, ptv-developer

I am looking for some JavaScript code that enables me to perform a drag-and-drop routing based on Leaflet through PTV Developer Routing API.

```js
var client = new RestClient("https://api.myptv.com/routing/v1/routes?waypoints=49.0133618,8.4277972&waypoints=48.8950289,8.6715602&options[trafficMode]=AVERAGE");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("apiKey", "YOUR_API_KEY");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```